# Collecting the coefficients of a term in Sympy

Tags: sympy

I have the following expression in Sympy

```
s = e0*a01*d1**2*u0 - e0*a01*d1**2*u1 - e0*a11*d1**2*u0 - e0*a11*d1**2*u1 + e0*d0*a00*d1*u1 + e0*d0*a01*d1*u0 + e0*d0*a10*d1*u0 - e0*d0*a11*d1*u1 + e0*d0*b0*u0 - e0*d0*b1*u1 + e0*d1*a00*d1*u0 - e0*d1*a01*d1*u1 - e0*d1*a10*d1*u1 - e0*d1*a11*d1*u0 - e0*d1*b0*u1 - e0*d1*b1*u0 - e1*a00*d1**2*u0 + e1*a00*d1**2*u1 + e1*a10*d1**2*u0 + e1*a10*d1**2*u1 - e1*d0*a00*d1*u0 + e1*d0*a01*d1*u1 + e1*d0*a10*d1*u1 + e1*d0*a11*d1*u0 + e1*d0*b0*u1 + e1*d0*b1*u0 + e1*d1*a00*d1*u1 + e1*d1*a01*d1*u0 + e1*d1*a10*d1*u0 - e1*d1*a11*d1*u1 + e1*d1*b0*u0 - e1*d1*b1*u1
```

So first I simpify it:

`s = sympify(s,locals=T)`

(T contains all these symbols in the string, that are non commutative). And I want to get the coefficient of

```
d1**2*u0
```

after "factoring" it. So I did the following:

```
e=sympify(d1**2*u0,locals=T)
collected_expr = collect(s,e,exact=True)
print(collected_expr)
coeff = collected_expr.coeff(e)
print(coeff)
```

The result of collected_expr is ok:

```
d1**2*u0*(e0*a01 - e0*a11 - e1*a00 + e1*a10) - e0*a01*d1**2*u1 - e0*a11*d1**2*u1 + e0*d0*a00*d1*u1 + e0*d0*a01*d1*u0 + e0*d0*a10*d1*u0 - e0*d0*a11*d1*u1 + e0*d0*b0*u0 - e0*d0*b1*u1 + e0*d1*a00*d1*u0 - e0*d1*a01*d1*u1 - e0*d1*a10*d1*u1 - e0*d1*a11*d1*u0 - e0*d1*b0*u1 - e0*d1*b1*u0 + e1*a00*d1**2*u1 + e1*a10*d1**2*u1 - e1*d0*a00*d1*u0 + e1*d0*a01*d1*u1 + e1*d0*a10*d1*u1 + e1*d0*a11*d1*u0 + e1*d0*b0*u1 + e1*d0*b1*u0 + e1*d1*a00*d1*u1 + e1*d1*a01*d1*u0 + e1*d1*a10*d1*u0 - e1*d1*a11*d1*u1 + e1*d1*b0*u0 - e1*d1*b1*u1
```

But coeff is not ok, as it returns 1, but I really want

```
e0*a01 - e0*a11 - e1*a00 + e1*a10
```

EDIT: I also tried

```
coeff = collected_expr.coeff(u0).coeff(d1).coeff(d1)
```

and

```
coeff = collected_expr.coeff(u0).coeff(d1**2)
```

But both things returned 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docstring of Expr.coeff says

> When `x` is noncommutative, the coefficient to the left (default) or
>   right of `x` can be returned. The keyword 'right' is ignored when
>   `x` is commutative.

collect does not seem to be noncommutative-aware, however, so the factors that were on the right may collect to the left.

```
>>> var("A B", commutative=False)
(A, B)
>>> collect(A*B+B*A**2,B)
B*(A + A**2)
```